# Render Markdown in text that's coming from a live preview in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a website with ruby on rails where people can make posts and what not. The posts use Markdown for rendering the text just like Stack Overflow. Whenever a user is making a post, there is a live preview `div` right beneath the text area that show's the user what their post will look like, just like here on stack overflow. My problem is I don't know how to get the Markdown to render on the live preview.

My javascript code for the live preview is

```
window.onload = function(){
var idea = document.getElementById("idea-text");
try{
    idea.onkeyup = idea.onkeypress = function(){
        document.getElementById('live-preview').innerHTML = this.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    }
}
catch(e){
}
}
```

The text will always be plain text, any pointers on making the Markdown render?

**Edit**:

My solution to my dilemma was to use markdown-js from https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js Figuring out how to use this with node was painful however because I ran into multiple problems. I found a solution on https://rails-assets.org/#/components/markdown which provided a simple three step solution to my problem! My code to show a live-preview of text that renders mark down is

```
window.onload = function(){
var idea = document.getElementById("idea-text");
try{
    idea.onkeyup = idea.onkeypress = function(){
        document.getElementById('live-preview').innerHTML = markdown.toHTML(this.value);
    }
}
catch(e){
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a library like [**markdown-js**](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) that expose a simple method to convert a markdown conte in html, then directly inject your html in your preview div.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this. I've got to ask my team lead to install npm on the server, then I'll see if this method works.

Comment: There's a client of the same library [here](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/releases)

I still largely recomend the use of node. It's an awesome tool for a FE Developer. ;)

Comment: Thanks again Davide for the suggestion, I posted my full solution in my main post.

Comment: "This repo is no longer maintained." However, there are some recommendations on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure StackOverflow uses [PageDown](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wiki) to do the translation from markdown to HTML in JavaScript.

> PageDown is the JavaScript Markdown previewer used on Stack Overflow and the rest of the Stack Exchange network. It includes a Markdown-to-HTML converter and an in-page Markdown editor with live preview.

You could conceivably do something like this in the end:

```
var converter = new pagedown.Converter();

idea.onkeyup = idea.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('live-preview').innerHTML = converter.makeHtml(this.value);
}
```